# Jenkins kubernetes-plugin talking to multiple clusters

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-kubernetes

so the issue I am having and struggling to understand is how to setup multiple clouds/clusters. Very similar to this question.
[One Jenkins, Two Kubernetes Clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029596/one-jenkins-two-kubernetes-clusters)

Basically I have jenkins perfectly running in cluster A. Cluster B is where I'm having issues. I have cluster b kubernetes setup in the plugin as cluster B. I can hit the login button and it works as expected. The problem im having is when a agent deploys to cluster b to do work, it can no longer talk back. The errors appears to be because my jenkins is behind a https endpoint. However I cannot find where to setup ssl? And even if I get past that, I'm not certain as how to let jnlp talk back? Would that be a nodeport? I looked at websocket but I'm still having issues. 
Everything online I find does not appear to answer jenkins behind https. They all appear to assume it's http.
Any guidance is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so to close the loop on what I ended up doing. I used the kubernetes-cli plugin in the end. This way agents got spun in in cluster A, and were able to trigger deployments etc in cluster B.
The kubernetes-cli plugin only required a service account on cluster A in order to interact with the cluster. So actually a perfect solution.