# Jenkins with nginx using docker Port 50000 config

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins, docker-compose, gitlab

I am using Jenkins and Nginx both in Docker,

From Jenkins docker documentation, it seems that jenkins need 2 ports, 50000 and 8080, **Reference : https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md**

Nginx acting as reverse proxy has this configuration right now

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.domain.com
    www.jenkins.domain.com;

    server_tokens off;
 
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://jenkins.domain.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.jenkins.domain.com;
    server_tokens off;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.domain;    
    return 301 https://jenkins.domain.com$request_uri;   
}

# configuration of the server
server {

    listen      443 ssl http2;
    server_name jenkins.domain.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/jenkins_access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/jenkins_error.log;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.domain;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip_conf;
   
    server_tokens off;



    location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://jenkins:8080;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://jenkins:8080 https://jenkins.domain.com;


      # Required for new HTTP-based CLI


      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_request_buffering off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      add_header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' 'jenkins.domain.com:50000' always;
    }
}
```

**Reference for nginx config : http://web.archive.org/web/20190723112236/https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy**

and this works perfectly fine to serve Jenkins website ,but i get error

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Request headers:
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: GitLab/14.0.0-pre
X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook
Request body:
{
  "object_kind": "push",
  "event_name": "push",
  "before": "e7f7c62995e68446fb1c519fb7f2316eb083bb83",
  "after": "9d62e92972ed32ca67c09108395ebad9a20f3e92",
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "checkout_sha": "9d62e92972ed32ca67c09108395ebad9a20f3e92",
  "message": null,
  "user_id": 4642285,
  "user_name": "Abstract Aesthetics",
  "user_username": "4bstractanimation",
  "user_email": "",
  "user_avatar": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/99a9286c8eaf9b7335f91c3ddbdad7fd?s=80&d=identicon",
  "project_id": 26279073,
  "project": {
    "id": 26279073,
    "name": "ucurs-default-shop",
    "description": "",
    "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop",
    "avatar_url": null,
    "git_ssh_url": "git@gitlab.com:4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop.git",
    "git_http_url": "https://gitlab.com/4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop.git",
    "namespace": "Abstract Aesthetics",
    "visibility_level": 0,
    "path_with_namespace": "4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop",
    "default_branch": "master",
    "ci_config_path": "",
    "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop",
    "url": "git@gitlab.com:4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@gitlab.com:4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop.git",
    "http_url": "https://gitlab.com/4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop.git"
  },
  "commits": [
    {
      "id": "9d62e92972ed32ca67c09108395ebad9a20f3e92",
      "message": "theme updated\n",
      "title": "theme updated",
      "timestamp": "2021-05-31T20:45:11+05:00",
      "url": "https://gitlab.com/4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop/-/commit/9d62e92972ed32ca67c09108395ebad9a20f3e92",
      "author": {
        "name": "Abstract Aesthetics",
        "email": "4bstractanimation@gmail.com"
      },
      "added": [

      ],
      "modified": [
        "public/index.html"
      ],
      "removed": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "6eaf6296ce2a7215431ae2e641fd64159fd26be0",
      "message": "theme updated\n",
      "title": "theme updated",
      "timestamp": "2021-05-31T20:44:57+05:00",
      "url": "https://gitlab.com/4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop/-/commit/6eaf6296ce2a7215431ae2e641fd64159fd26be0",
      "author": {
        "name": "Abstract Aesthetics",
        "email": "4bstractanimation@gmail.com"
      },
      "added": [
        "src/components/admin-view/images/logo_feild.js"
      ],
      "modified": [
        "src/StateStore/reducer.js",
        "src/components/admin-view/images/index.js",
        "src/components/admin-view/information/TextView.js",
        "src/components/admin-view/information/index.js",
        "src/components/layout/footer/index.js",
        "src/components/layout/header/index.js"
      ],
      "removed": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "e7f7c62995e68446fb1c519fb7f2316eb083bb83",
      "message": "theme updated\n",
      "title": "theme updated",
      "timestamp": "2021-05-31T19:38:49+05:00",
      "url": "https://gitlab.com/4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop/-/commit/e7f7c62995e68446fb1c519fb7f2316eb083bb83",
      "author": {
        "name": "Abstract Aesthetics",
        "email": "4bstractanimation@gmail.com"
      },
      "added": [
        "src/components/customers-view/filter-product/price_filter.js"
      ],
      "modified": [
        "public/index.html",
        "src/components/customers-view/filter-product/index.js",
        "src/components/customers-view/populated-view/index.js",
        "src/components/customers-view/single-product-card/index.js",
        "src/components/customers-view/single-product-view/index.js"
      ],
      "removed": [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "total_commits_count": 3,
  "push_options": {
  },
  "repository": {
    "name": "ucurs-default-shop",
    "url": "git@gitlab.com:4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop.git",
    "description": "",
    "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop",
    "git_http_url": "https://gitlab.com/4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop.git",
    "git_ssh_url": "git@gitlab.com:4bstractanimation/django-standard-shop.git",
    "visibility_level": 0
  }
}
```

when i try to connect GitLab to jenkins.

how can i configure nginx to also serv port 50000 of jenkins over ssl
My docker compose enviroment :

```
version: "3.4"

services:

# JENKINS

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/Jenkins:/var/jenkins_home   


# NGINX SERVER
  nginx_server:
    image: webdevops/php-nginx:7.3
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${PWD}/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - ${PWD}/../get-cert/data/certbot/conf:/certs
    ports:
      - 80:80    # app port
      - 443:443
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: nginx_server
#####################################################
```

**EDIT**
The problem is actually with SSL in general, as i tried running

```
curl jenkins.domain.com
```

and it gave the following error

```
    curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I recreated the SSL certificate, yet still the same error, although in browser it seems to validate my ssl certificate

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729686/jenkins-how-to-configure-jenkins-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-jnlp-slaves-to

Comment: problem is actually with SSL, i edited the post and added logs for curl, kindly view again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was probably some cache issue, as it worked when i commented some code in nginx for proxy headers.
and restarted the server
after that i un commented that code again and restarted server, it still worked.